# Matlab FFT showing multiple peaks instead of one

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a data file which has column 1 as time and column 2 as some response variable. Here is the image of my time series.

[image]

I was calculating fft of this time series and was expecting a single peak but instead got multiple peaks as shown below: (on x-axis I have time period instead of frequency)

[image]

Notice that the second peak(with lesser amplitude) has roughly half the time period of the highest peak. To me, this does not look like harmonics. 
What could these other peaks signify ? Does this "periodic looking" time series is actually quasi-periodic ?

I'm using FFT for the first time, however, I have checked my code for known functions like sine wave and it works fine with them showing only single period.

Function for fft :

```
function [X,freq]=FFT1(x,Fs)

N=length(x); %get the number of points

k=0:N-1; %create a vector from 0 to N-1

T=N/Fs; %get the frequency interval

freq=k/T; %create the frequency range

X=fft(x)/N; % normalize the data

cutOff = ceil(N/2);

X = X(1:cutOff);

freq = freq(1:cutOff);
```

and the main script is :

```
filename = 'e=0_TS_P1_S408080.dat';

m = dlmread(filename);

m = m(1:end-1,:);

s1 = m(:,2)';
s2 = m(:,3)';
t  = m(:,1)';
%s1 = sin(t);

dt = t(2)-t(1);
fs = 1.0/dt;

[YfreqDomain,frequencyRange] = FFT1(s1,fs);

fig_fft1 = figure;

timeperiod = 1.0./frequencyRange;

plot(timeperiod,abs(YfreqDomain));

set(fig_fft1,'Position',[500,500,500,300])

xlabel('Time period')
ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Comment: eh.... Unless your signal is a perfect sin/cos the FFT can have more than 1 peak. Or any shape. What does it mean? That your signal can be decomposed of those sin frequencies.... thats what FFT is, rigth?

Comment: This peak is weird looking, based on its position and location, it is unlikely to be spectral leakage, which means it must somehow exist in your sinewave, please post the code to your sine wave so we can attempt to recreate it. Yes, it does look like the harmonics, but a perfect sinewave should not have them.

Comment: Yeah your signal is a sum of two sinusoids! It doesn't look like a perfect sinusoids (the troughs are misshapen). It could be aliasing, could potentially be harmonics. What's the data, how did you collect it?

Comment: well there's your answer - your Sine wave is not just a single Sine Wave, but consists of other Smaller Sine waves - now I look at the plot, it does not look like a Sine Wave, you are loading the data from `'0_TS_P1_S408080.dat` so the FFT result correctly shows the other frequencies present in your "Sine Wave"

Comment: @AhmedFasih. More like five sinusoids and a whole bunch of other cruft.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Actually, it looks like a few Harmonics of a Triangle Wave (or Sawtooth) at the same frequency as the main sine wave - the positioning of the frequencies does not look random and I think it is too much of a coincidence...

Comment: Thanks ! Actually, it is just some periodic signal coming from the data file, not even a sine wave..but still if you look at the first figure(time series), it looks like(to my eye) that there is a single frequency.. and theory behind the result also predicts it to be single frequency !

Comment: @AhmedFasih : The data is coming from the simulation of some ordinary differential equations. In theory, the answer should be a periodic behavior. But if i believe the fft results, it turns out to be quasi-periodic(more than one frequency)..

Comment: To my eye, the periods in the time domain are definitely asymmetric. Two sanity checks you could do to convince yourself that the data is well represented by the FFT would be to plot the data on a polar plot using the fundamental frequency as one period along with a pure sine wave at that same frequency. Your data will be squished in one direction. Similarly, plot one or two periods on top of the same data reversed in time. If its symmetric, the two will lay right on top of one another. Your data won't.

Comment: Your result is very periodic. Periodic does not mean that there is only one frequency, just that the frequency components don't change in time.

Comment: If the ODE’s analytical solution is a single sinusoid but this numerical solution shows multiple sinusoids (it certainly does), try running your ODE solver with smaller step sizes?

Comment: Some ODE's have plural solution modes (perhaps related to initial conditions or boundary values) that correspond to an overtone sequence, which your plot clearly shows in reciprocal form (periodicities instead of frequencies).